# SSL is messing up/ disabling jquery

Tags: jquery, ssl

I have SSL enabled for my shopping cart, register, login and contact form. When SSL is enabled the jquery is disabled. I see google has jquery importing with https aswell.

Here is the page https://americanbookcompany.com/store/account/ when you click CREATE ONE NOW at the top, it does not execute the JQUERY to switch the form. Works perfect without SSL.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems like you have a few `.js` files called from non-secure urls

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://sdscdn.userreport.com/popup.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://tab-slide-out.googlecode.com/files/jquery.tabSlideOut.v1.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/americanbookco.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=4" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I can't be certain this is the only reason but my `SSL` was very sensitive to things like this.  Maybe storing these files locally and making sure all `http` connections are secure might be the first step.

Comment: Chrome definitely complains about that: 
[blocked] The page at https://americanbookcompany.com/store/account/ ran insecure content from http://tab-slide-out.googlecode.com/files/jquery.tabSlideOut.v1.3.js
and then 
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tabSlideOut'

Comment: The reason is that all resources loaded from a page loaded via HTTPS should also be loaded using HTTPS.

Comment: I actually thought about that before posting this, I figured SSL would of blocked all unsecure incoming connections as it makes a lot of since. That fixed it guys, thank you very much for the fast reply.

Comment: @tq Thanks, I do not think I have any external images importing right now, but I will double check. Thanks again!